# How do I tell Microsoft Outlook to minimize to the System Tray?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, taskbar, notification-area

When I click on minimize in Outlook, I would like to minimize to the System Tray, not the Taskbar. How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Right click on the Outlook icon in the systray
- Select "Hide when minimized"