# How can I make Outlook close to the system tray?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, taskbar, notification-area

When I close a window in Outlook, I want the program to minimize to the taskbar so I can continue receiving email notifications as I work.

I know it's possible to have Outlook [minimize to the system tray](https://superuser.com/q/18911/358766), but programs like Skype, Steam, and Discord have gotten me used to programs continuing to run in the background when closed.

**How can I make Outlook close to to the taskbar, so it can continue running in the background?**

Comment: Teams does this. You can *close* the window, so the application does not appear in the Alt-Tab list. This de-clutters the workflow while making the app readily available from the system tray with no start-up penalty. Consistent with Windows inconsistency, Outlook does it a different way. It has the "hide on minimise" feature, which if selected, "disappears" Outlook when you *minimise* the window, enabling it to be brought back from the system tray, and it doesn't appear in the Alt-Tab list while minimised with this setting. But it can't tolerate a *close*. That will still close Outlook. Win 11

Answer (score 2):

The [Quick Tweaks](http://www.reliefjet.com/Quicks/Features/QuickTweaks) plugin has a setting to minimize on close, and says it supports Outlook 2010. Not sure if it would still minimize to the system tray if you have that selected in Outlook.